# Can’t figure out how to make a door disappear using SetActive(False) once the player picks up four coins in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm working on a 3D rendition of Roll-A-Ball, and no matter what method I approach, I can’t get the door to disappear using SetActive this is what I have right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] float movementSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 5f;
    int coins = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y, verticalInput * movementSpeed);

         if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            coins++;
            Debug.Log("Coins: " + coins);
        }
                 
     if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Door") && coins == 4)
         {
            
              gameObject.SetActive(false);
        
         }
    }
}
```

I made the door out of four different parts (not sure if that was the best option) and I tagged the part that I want to disappear as Door. Issue is, not only does this method not work, but I also don't want to rely on an OnTriggerEnter because I don't want to have to touch the door for it to open. I'd like for the door to just disappear as soon as the coin count is 4. [Door setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afbdp.jpg)

I’ve been researching and trying a bunch of different approaches, but none worked.I feel like it's such a simple answer that I'm just not seeing.
I've tried putting an if statement for the door under void update and it didn't work.
I also tried setting a variable to find the Door game object in the beginning and then putting an if statement.

Comment: There are many options. The easiest is to have some form of "l achieved" code and when each of the 4 keys have been collected. Disable door. If you use properties on setting a key to yes it will trigger a method to say are all these things true if so. Do y.

Comment: It looks like this script is being applied to the Player and not on the Door gameObject, so when you run the SetActive(false), you're running that on the player. If you add a public GameObject Door in the script, then in Unity drag the door from the hierarchy to that variable, then on your coins==4, you could do Door.SetActive(false); and that might get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing the GameObject to disable:

```cs
if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Door") && coins == 4){    
    // Missing the 'other'
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
       
}
```